# How can i join vertex of the same bezier?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have to complete a 3d job and I think that for this piece it is best to use bezier or curves. I am a little novice with these tools and I can't find a way to draw "a bridge" between some vertices.

I tried with the <kbd>F</kbd> key but it does not let me connect them and it is not enough just to join 2 but it would have to be 4: (with the photos I hope that I understand better).

The piece is somewhat complex and I only manage to do it on the one side. My idea is to avoid  polygonal modeling as much as possible.[image: sp]

Comment: You can't create branching in curves. Delete a segment first or disable cyclic with alt+c.

Answer (score 1):

You can only make a cyclic curve, there is no way to join it multiple times as far as I know.